# Trouble with bruteforce hydra linux

Tags: hydra

I have a trouble with hydra in kali linux that when i used to brutforce my gmail , it didn't give me the correct password 
can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you read through [their documentation](https://www.thc.org/thc-hydra/)?  Can you post the command you're using?  Can you provide any more details as to what the error is, or any output that you see?

Answer (score 7):

It is not recommended to brute force Gmail. Hydra should be used in test environments (local) or environments that are to be tested for which you have received an approval.

To put it bluntly, you will not be helped in attacking Gmail, even if it is your own account.

Comment: can you tell me a good tools to bruteforce gmail?